# How to download objects from svn repository to unix AIX

Tags: unix, ssl, svn, curl

I am unable to download file's from svn repository into unix AIX system. I am using "curl" command in unix to download the file but it fails with below error

curl: (60) SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

command used : 
curl -u username:password http://server.com/svn/trunk/test.file

Are there any settings in subversion repository which i need to change to make the curl command work.If yes, then how to change them.

I cannot use wget because it is not installed on our machine the alternative is curl.

Please, help me download subversion files into unix. your help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Sri

Answer (score 1):

The short way to do it would be to add the `--insecure` option to the curl command.  This tells cURL to ignore the fact that it can't verify the signer of the SSL cert used by your SVN server.

```
curl -u username:password --insecure https://server.com/svn/trunk/test.file
```

The error is happening for one of two reasons, either your SVN access is secured using a self-signed certificate from a CA not in the certificate chain for the OS, or the trusted certs cURL is using is outdated and doesn't have a certificate from the CA that signed your SVN SSL certificate.

You can either download the root certificate that signed your SSL cert and specify it like: `curl --cacert /path/to/cert.pem`.  Otherwise, you'll need to determine how and where to install additional certificates to be trusted.  This partly depends on whether or not cURL is using OpenSSL or NSS.  [This site](http://kb.kerio.com/product/kerio-connect/server-configuration/ssl-certificates/adding-trusted-root-certificates-to-the-server-1605.html) has some guidance on how to do this for various operating systems.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have changed the command to curl -k http://server.com/svn/trunk/test.file -u username:password > test.file and it worked.

Thanks, Sri

Comment: Glad that did the trick.  You can mark this answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for your response. I have changed the command to 
curl -k http://server.com/svn/trunk/test.file -u username:password > test.file
and it worked.

Thanks,
Sri